# Upgrading to firefox 3.6.12 results in problems

Tags: xorg, redhat-enterprise-linux, firefox-3.6

Upgrading firefox to 3.6.12 causes the Xorg process to run @ 100% CPU time.

- OS is: Red Hat Enterprise Linux
  Client release 5.4 (Tikanga)
- Previous
  version of firefox: 3.01
- New version
  of firefox: 3.6.12
- Other changes:
  upgraded libflashplayer.so from adobe
  website

Note that the previous version of firefox is still installed at /usr/bin - I have to start the new version of firefox using: ~/bin/firefox/firefox -no-remote.

As mentioned, when using firefox 3.6.12 with all add-ons disabled, something triggers the Xorg process to run @ 100% (as viewed by top) - memory consumption remains normal. For example, opening http://grigio.org/pimp_my_gedit_was_textmate_linux triggers this problem. Memory usage remains normal during this time. Opening up the *same* set of pages (as the session information is stored by my profile) using firefox 3.0.1 does not cause any problems.

Comment: I've had no end of problems with 3.6.x versions of Firefox and finally switched to Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You can try renaming (or removing)  ~/.mozilla to see if it solves the problem. You can also un-install 3.6.12 and install 3.0.1 manually.